# jquery mobile - datebox appears too much on the left

Tags: jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 and jqm-datebox 'stable'.

Code:

```
<label class="ui-input-text ui-hidden-accessible" for="date">Date</label>
<input jql id="date" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset" type="text" value="" name="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "calStartDay": 1}'></input>
```

When I click on the little icon, though, the calendar box appears too much to the left, as in picture. This is particularly evident on a mobile device.

If I reduce the width of the window it goes even further left.
The `element.style` (especially the `left` attribute) appears to be calculated on the fly, depending on the width, but I can't manage to find where, neither in the css, nor in the js.
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115541/jquery-mobile-datebox-custom-alignment), kinda similar to mine, but I don't find it applicable to my case.

How should I go to make the box show in its entirety?

[image: calendar box goes out of the page]

Comment: give 'centerHoriz': true a shot (add it to the options)

Comment: sorry, hadn't seen this. i'm on vacation now, will try when i'm back at the office! will let you know, thanks! :)

Comment: Ok, I tried. It works in the sense that it centers horizontally under the textbox, but in this way it still goes 'out' of the window. Any other idea? I checked through the options list, but there is no 'alignRight' or similar.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

```
<input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"calbox", "centerHoriz": true}'>
```

The centerHoriz option will get you what you want.

Comment: You mean like JTSage posted in July?

Comment: I second @OlleSjögren's comment. It also doesn't work in my case, as I said.